# How to attach more than one file to a xaml in solution explorer window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This is what I see in the solution explorer (simple wpf project):

[image: what I have]

This is what I would like to have:

[image: what I want]

There are **two** files dependent of the `MainWindow.xaml`

The obvious drag & drop of `MainWindowViewModel.cs` to `MainWindow.xaml` yields an error

> can't move file. Same destination
>   folder.

How can I achieve this? Should be simple, but I can't find it ...

Thanks for any hints

Comment: Is this a partial class?

Comment: @Daniel: No, MainWindowViewModel is no partial class. Only MainWindow.xaml.cs is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that from within visual studio as far as i know. You can however manually edit the .csproj file and modify the `Compile Include` element for your viewmodel like this:

```
<Compile Include="MainWindowViewModel.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
```

I havent actually done this in practice but it should get you what you want. However beware that visual studio might think thats is a generated file and delete it when you save the xamlfile, so make sure you backup your work before trying

-edit-

Did a quick test and it seems to work, visual studio doesnt seem to mind or interfere either.

Comment: I was just typing the same thing: I've done it that way and it worked without problems, but its a pain you need to close the project and do it manually...

Comment: You should probably note that this is extremely bad practice if the file doesn't actually contain a partial definition of the same class as its parent...

Comment: it is a bit of a pain, i agree.. you can use the [PowerCommands for visual studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99/) to get a `Edit Project file` menu option in solution explorer to make it a bit easier. also since project files are just xml, you could use something like linqpad and XElement to loop through a whole bunch of them and modify each compile element

Comment: @J.Steen: This is proposed by Karl Shifflett (microsoft mvp) in his introduction to mvvm. It's intended to show the close relationship of the view to its viewmodel. I actually think it is a nice practice! http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/in-the-box-ndash-mvvm-training/

Comment: @nabulke, Gosh! Well, proposed by an MVP doesn't automatically mean best practice, but I see your point. ;)